# String replace From [ to ]

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I am making a research compiler in C# and am currently attempting to scrape wikipedia. My problem is that the information from wikipedia comes with these numbers in square brackets, e.g. [1], [46], [77].

How can I remove all of these without having to manually put them all into a string array which I have already tried but some of them are extremely high (200+).

Thanks.

Comment: can you look up the string.Replace() method also show what your current coded logic looks like so that we can see how you have implemented and or are using the string array..?

Comment: The Replace method on String is not really suitable for what you need.  You may want to consider using a faster algorithm that's optimized for longer text, such as the Boyer-Moore string-matching algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory do it with *Regular Expression* pattern, `"\\[([^\\s]*)\\]"` that in theory should return the bracket and the inner contents of said bracket.

```
// Sample:
var sample = @"Richard was killed fighting Henry Tudor in 1485[1] Following his death, Richard's body was stripped naked and taken to Leicester[2][3]";
var content = Regex.Replace(sample, "\\[([^\\s]*)\\]", String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(content);

// Output:
Richard was killed fighting Henry Tudor in 1485 Following his death, Richard's body was stripped naked and taken to Leicester
```

Not sure if that is what you are seeking, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will use regular expressions to remove anything within [] from in the input string:

```
string regex = "(\\[.*\\])";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, string.Empty);
```